# Is a differentiable function on $(-2, 4)$ always integrable on $[-2, 4]$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, continuity, examples-counterexamples

So my question is, say I have a function that is differentiable on $(-2, 4)$. Is it always integrable on $[-2, 4]$?

I know that if $f$ is diff on $(-2, 4)$, then it is continuous on $(-2, 4)$. And I also know that if $f$ is continuous on $[-2, 4]$ then it is integrable on $[-2, 4]$. However, I am wondering if there is such a function so that there would be a problem at the endpoints of the closed interval so that it is differentiable on the open interval, but not integrable on the closed interval.

Comment: See [Volterra's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra's_function).

Comment: There are a couple great books with titles like "famous counter-examples in mathematics" ... here are two such: http://smile.amazon.com/Counterexamples-Analysis-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486428753/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1417288404&sr=8-1&keywords=counter-examples+in+math  and http://smile.amazon.com/Counterexamples-Calculus-Classroom-Resource-Materials/dp/0883857650/ref=sr_1_8?ie=UTF8&qid=1417288404&sr=8-8&keywords=counter-examples+in+math

Comment: @Lucian: Could you explain why Volterra's function is of relevance?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The function $f(x)=\frac 1x$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$, yet it is not integrable on $[0,1]$.

**edit**

However, if you have a function $f$ which is differentiable on $[0,1]$, then it is necessarily continuous on $[0,1]$, hence measurable. Moreover, a continuous function on a compact is bounded, hence $f$ is bounded measurable, therefore integrable.

Comment: This is a little bit cheating. Can you give an example where the intervals are both closed?

Comment: @Mehrdad oops, my apologies, for some unknown reason I thought that you were the one who asked the initial question.

Comment: @Mehrdad It is not cheating, it is merely an answer to the initial question=) As for closed intervals, see edit.

Comment: Why don't you you answer the question with the given domain ?

Answer (score 20):

Generally no, but with additional assumption that it is bounded -- yes. For the unbounded case we have easy counterexamples, as $1/x$ or $1/\ln x$ on $(0,1)$.

Comment: It appears that the derivative of [Volterra's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function) is bounded, but not (Riemann) integrable.

Comment: @anorton Right, but its derivative is not differentiable.

Comment: $\ln x$ _is_ integrable on $[0,1]$, or maybe I misunderstand what you mean at the end there.

Comment: @alex.jordan Oh, my misprint! $1/\ln x$. Corrected.